# Importar libreria en Kotlin - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, studio

soy novato programando en Kotlin y no sé como se hace para poder importar una libreria por ejemplo como esta, https://github.com/santalu/maskara me da error de que no encuentra el repositorio y sin embargo si que existe, se que algo estoy haciendo mal pero no lo sé.
Muchas gracias de adelantado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el error está en que mi archivo build.gradle de proyecto no aparece el allprojects. Lo que he hecho al final y ha funcionado para mi es añadir el repositorio maven en el archivo settings.gradle de esta forma:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

y después añadir en el build.gradle la dependencia.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Revisa en el archivo `build.gradle` del módulo que la tengas de esta forma:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.santalu:maskara:1.0.0'
}
```

Y en el `build.gradle` de tu proyecto agregar los repos:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: En mi build.gradle de proyecto no me aparece el allprojects, al final lo he resuelto de otra manera, gracias igualmente!!